# Need regex for digits and dashes

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for this format `xxxx-xxx-xx.jpg` where `x` is digits `[0-9]`.

To match for example: `3402-560-27.jpg`

Comment: Give it a try yourself. You can do it!

Comment: This is not a "do your work for you" site. we like to see that some effort has been put into answering it yourself. Have you done any reading on regex? This is simple enough that it probably wouldn't take long to answer it yourself...

Comment: I know guys, and thats why I am embarrassed about asking for it. I'm a student and of course I've read about it, but I couldn't get the hang of it.. Though, after seeing the answer it became pretty clear. I guess I made it harder than it was. Once again, I'm sorry guys

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ -_-

Comment: The guys are being cranky this morning. It's hard to know where to start when you first approach regex. Now you have an idea of how it works so you can get a little further along next time before you come here to ask.

Comment: DOK, Thanks mate. No, I know it was stupid of me to ask so fast. But yes, now I've gained some understanding for it and hey! I actually got the answer I needed as fast as I needed it ^^ I won't be so eager asking next time!

Comment: @DOK Actually, at the end of awful working day (well, for me). :)

Comment: @aLoveForCoffee you should accept the most useful answer by click the tick mark next to it and a tip is don't ask for things `asap` it tends to piss people off, most question especially easy `regex` question will be answered very quickly anyway and try to demonstrate what you have tried yourself. Anyway glad you have learned something!

Comment: @sudo_O I ticked your answer a couple of minutes ago. Yeah, I know... As I said earlier; I'm sorry about that. Thanks guy, I'm off to tha interblag to learn some more regex!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `regex` is what you want:

```
\d{4}-\d{3}-\d{2}\.jpg
```

`\d` represents digits so `\d{4}` mean 4 digits.. in `regex` a `.` matches any single character so to match a literal `.` it needs to be escaped with a `\`.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the simplest regexes to write: put `\d` for each digit, `-` for each dash, and a `\.` for each dot. Letters correspond to themselves, so `jpg` goes in unchanged.

When you have more time, you can earn some "points for style" by learning about the [*explicit quantifier notation*](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for repeated groups.